# Adding instance of class variable to list and change them

Tags: java, instance, extend

I have a class that extends Module, and module has a list called values and a getter and adder.

In my class extending Module i write something like that

```
private ValueFloat threads = new ValueFloat("Threads", 2, 1, 5, 0);
```

and in constructor i write

```
addValue(threads);
```

now from somewhere else i loop through the values of one class extending Module and change them.

But from the class extending module, the return of threads.getValue(); is still the old.

whats the problem? please help!

ValueFloat class:

```
package me.niklasb.client.utils.ValueStuff;


import me.niklasb.client.main.Client;

public class ValueFloat extends Value {
    private String name;
    private float value;
    private float min;
    private float max;
    private int round;

    public ValueFloat(String name, float value, float min, float max, int round) {
        super(name);
        this.value = value;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.round = round;
    }

    public ValueFloat(String name, float value, float min, float max) {
        super(name);
        this.value = value;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.round = 1;
    }

    public float getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(float value) {
        this.value = value;
        Client.saveValues();
    }

    public int getRound() {
        return this.round;
    }

    public float getMin() {
        return this.min;
    }

    public float getMax() {
        return this.max;
    }
}
```

Example Module:

```
package me.niklasb.client.modules;

import com.darkmagician6.eventapi.EventTarget;
import me.niklasb.client.Category;
import me.niklasb.client.Mod;
import me.niklasb.client.Module;
import me.niklasb.client.event.UpdateEvent;
import me.niklasb.client.utils.TimeHelper;
import me.niklasb.client.utils.ValueStuff.ValueString;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;

import java.util.Random;

@Mod(name = "Spammer", keyCode = Keyboard.KEY_NONE, cat = Category.Misc)
public class Spammer extends Module {
    private Random random;
    private TimeHelper time;
    private ValueString text = new ValueString("Text", "@all Meow! Best client EU West!");

    public Spammer() {

        addValue(text);
        time = new TimeHelper();
        random = new Random();
    }

    @EventTarget
    private void onUpdate(UpdateEvent event) {
        if (mc.theWorld == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (this.time.isDelayComplete(10000L)) {
            Random randomNumber = new Random();
            for (int msg = 1; msg <= 10; msg++) {
                randomNumber.nextInt(100);
            }

            mc.thePlayer.sendChatMessage(text.getValue() + " " + random.nextInt(1337));

            time.setLastMS();
        }

    }


}
```

Basic gui element setting values:

```
ValueString valueString = (ValueString) value;


GuiTextField textField = new GuiTextField(valueString.getName(), valueString.getValue());

textField.addTextListener(new TextListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(char key, String text) {
        valueString.setValue(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void stringEntered(String text) {
        valueString.setValue(text);

    }
});

add(textField);
```

Values is declared in the superclass of, in example, "Spammer"

```
private String name;
private ArrayList<Value> values;

public Module() {

    values = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

in short:

Their is a variable declared in a class and a instance of this variable is saved in a list. now if i get one of those instances thorugh the list and change the value of it, i want that in the class where the variable gets declared, the value also changes.

Comment: Post a complete code example if you want help!

Comment: i cannot post everything those classes are really big

Comment: remove not relevant code

Comment: We have no idea what the definition of `values` in `Module` is, or how your class extends `Module`... and lots of other necessary context.  The definition of `ValueFloat` is probably the least important bit of information.

Comment: edited, dont know what else you need to know

Comment: what are you trying to do -- i'm not sure the question makes sense?..  Maybe post a smaller amount of code?

Comment: it makes sense. read it. Their is a variable declared in a class and an instance of this variable is saved in a list. now if i get one of those instances and change the value of it, i want that the value of variable in the class where i declared the variable also changes

Comment: Your question makes SOME sense, the problem is that you posted code that is not relevant to help you out. You mention `threads = new ValueFloat("Threads", 2, 1, 5, 0);` there is no such code in the classes you posted, also you mention "and in constructor i write" `addValue(threads);` Where is THIS constructor where is the RELEVANT code? That is what everyone is saying here. If you don't post relevant code we can't help you. YOU, and only you understand what you need, we have to look to the code you posted and try to understand. And because you didn't post RELEVANT code it makes no sense.

Comment: That is what @Robbo_UK is talking about.